# Происхождение выражения "битый час"

Tags: фразеология

"Я уже битый час жду его звонка" — то есть, очень долго.
А что такое вообще "битый час" и почему он "битый"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Это часы, они ходят... А иногда начинают бить : боммм! боммм!"

Наверное, выражение "битый час" произошло от того, что вот такие моменты длительного ожидания могли запоминаться из-за боя часов - больших напольных или маленьких карманных часов-"луковиц", которые тоже были с музыкальным звоном.

Answer (score 0):

Учебный фразеологический словарь:

> > Битый час — очень долго, целый час (обычно о времени, потраченном напрасно, впустую). Связано с боем настенных часов, которые бьют каждый час.

Возможно, с этим выражением связано другое: "убивать время".